# Best method to add noise on tf.dataset images "on the fly"

Tags: python, tensorflow

After training a model (image classification) I would like to see how it performs differently when I evaluate a proper image and various noised versions of it.

The type of noise I'm thinking is a random change in pixels value, I tried with this approach:

```py
# --Inside the generator function that I provide to model.predict_generator--
# dataset is a numpy array with denoised images path
dt = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(lambda: image_generator(dataset), output_types=(tf.float32))
```

```py
def image_generator_(image_paths):
    for path in image_paths:
        # im is keras.preprocessing image
        img = im.load_img(path,
                          color_mode='rgb',
                          target_size=(224,224))

        img_to_numpy = np.array(img)

        for _ in range (0, 5):
            tmp_numpy_image = img_to_numpy.copy()
            for i in range(tmp_numpy_image.shape[0]): 
                for j in range(tmp_numpy_image.shape[1]):
                    # add noise
                    tmp_numpy_image.shape[i][j] = ...
            yield tmp_numpy_image
```

This process works fine but it is very slow. I also use dataset.batch and dataset.prefetch on **dt** and I didn't found a combination for their values that reduces the algorithm time

Is there a smarter way to do it? I tried by yielding not noised images and to add the noise later inside dataset.map. The problem is that inside map I have to manipulate tensors and I didn't found a way to change each pixel value

---

**SOLUTION**

I used @Marat approach and it worked like a charm, the whole process went from 20-30 hours to minutes. My noise was a simple +-1 but I didn't want to go in overflow (255+1 = 0 in uint8) and therefore I only had to use numpy masks

```
...
tmp_numpy_image = img_to_numpy.copy()

noise = np.random.randint(-1, 1, img_to_numpy.shape)

# tmp_numpy_imag will become of type int32
tmp_numpy_image = tmp_numpy_image + noise

np.putmask(tmp_numpy_image, tmp_numpy_image < 0, 0)
np.putmask(tmp_numpy_image, tmp_numpy_image > 255, 255)

tmp_numpy_image = tmp_numpy_image.astype('uint8') 

yield tmp_numpy_image
```

Comment: Precompute noise, add it to each image in parallel?

Comment: Don't think I can, the noise is dependent on each pixel values, for example if channel R (RGB) is 255 and the random noise would be a +1, I discard that noise because 255->0 is too much

Comment: Then precompute noise and the image is then the sum or the max channel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest overhead here is pixel operations (double for loop). Vectorizing it should result in substantial speedup:

```
noise_magnitude = 10
...
    img_max_value = img_to_numpy.max() * np.ones(img_to_numpy.shape)
    for _ in range (0, 5):
        # depending on range of values, you might want to adjust noise magnitude
        noise = np.random.randint(0, noise_magnitude, img_to_numpy.shape)
        # after adding noise, clip values exceeding max values
        yield np.maximum(img_to_numpy + noise, img_max_value)
```

Comment: I change pixel by pixel because I only change one random channel (RGB) and if the noise (-1 or +1) would lead into overflow (255 + 1->0 or 0 - 1-->255) I discard it. I'll see if I can vectorize it anyway